# Having both object.property and object.property.method() available in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

[update]
My question may not be clear enough... 
Further clarification of what I would like to accomplish :

I retrieve objects like this one:

```
p =
  name:
    first: 'alan'
    last: 'smith'
```

and want to create a structure (one class, multiple classes ?) to be able to write things like this ultimately:

```
person.name # alan smith
person.name.toCap() #Alan Smith
person.name.first # alan
person.name.first.toCap() # Alan
person.name.last # smith
person.name.last.toCap() # Smith
...
```

so :

1. Is there a way to have both person.name and person.name.first ?
2. Is there a better way to extend object properties with methods rather than extending native types like *String* ?

---

[original]

Looking for the right way to do this in coffee :

```
console.log person.name.last #smith
console.log person.name.last.capitalize() # SMITH
console.log person.name.last.initial() # S
```

I have come up with the following solution, but would like to make sure this is the way to go...

```
String::toCap = (remainingToLower=false) -> 
  @[0].toUpperCase() + if remainingToLower then @[1..-1].toLowerCase() 
                                           else @[1..-1]
Number::random = (percent) ->
  offset = @ * percent / 100
  parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 * offset) + @ - offset)

class Name
  constructor: (@first, @last) ->

class Person
  constructor: (@name, @age) ->
  toString: () => "#{@name.first.toCap(true)} #{@name.last.toCap(true)} 
                  (#{@age.random(25)})"

# GO --------------------------->

p = new Person(new Name, 18)
p.name.first = 'alaN'
p.name.last = 'smith'

console.log "#{p.toString()}"
```

Thanks for your feedback.

[Plunk Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ovwj7z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Context**
I have this raw data:

```
data =
  name:
    first: 'alan'
    last: 'smith'  
  age: 18  
  address: [  
    {  
      name: 'work'  
      street: '1600 amphitheatre parkway'  
      city: 'mountain view'  
      zip: 'CA 94043'  
    },{  
      name: 'home'  
      street: '1 infinite loop'  
      city: 'cupertino'  
      zip: 'CA 95014'  
    }]
```

And want to create a structure to manipulate my data like this :

```
p = New Person(data)
console.log """
  #{p}                        # alan smith (18), 2 address lines
  #{p.name},                  # alan smith
  #{p.name.first},            # alan
  #{p.address}                # 2 address lines
  #{p.address.work}           # 1600 amphitheatre parkway, mountain view, CA 94043
  #{p.address.work.street}    # 1600 amphitheatre parkway
"""
```

Additionally, I want to be able to apply custom methods to any member. 
For instance, assuming toCap() is a method that capitalises each word of a String :

```
console.log """
  #{p.name.toCap()},                # Alan Smith
  #{p.name.first.toCap()}           # Alan
  #{p.address.work.toCap()}         # 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Moutain View, CA 94043
  #{p.address.work.street.toCap()}  # 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway  
"""
```

---

**Solution** (see this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ovwj7z) for the full code)

- use nested classes

  ```
  class Person
    constructor: (data) ->
      @name = new Name(data.name)
      @address = new AddressList(data.address)
  ```
- create members dynamically

  ```
  class AddressList
    constructor: (list) ->    
      @[addr.name] = new Address(addr) for addr in list
  ```
- wrap your properties or use base classes rather than extending native objects

  ```
  class StringProperty
    constructor: (@_value) ->
    toString: => 
      @_value
    toCap: (remainingToLower=false) =>
      _words = @_value.split ' '
      (@_toCap(w,remainingToLower) for w in _words).join ' '     
    _toCap : (s, r) ->
      s[0].toUpperCase() + if r then s[1..-1].toLowerCase() else s[1..-1]
  ```

  ... and use them directly ...

  ```
  class Name
    constructor: (name) ->
      @first = new StringProperty(name.first)
      @last = new StringProperty(name.last)
    toString: =>
      "#{@first} #{@last}"
    toCap: =>
      "#{@first.toCap()} #{@last.toCap()}"
  ```

  ... or create members dynamically :

  ```
  @[k] = new StringProperty(data[k]) for k of data when k in Address.fields
  ```
- don't forget to override toString() as above